# SQL not executing from cmd command

Tags: oracle, cmd, sqlcl

If I run this command in a command prompt window:

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql /nolog
```

sqlcl opens and, if I type:

```
show tns
```

My mapped TNSNames are listed.

However, if I go with a single line in cmd:

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql /nolog show tns
```

SQLCL opens but it closes immediately showing an error I cannot see (it closes very quickly, almost instantly).
What would be the way to fix this and make it behave like the above 2 commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql /nolog & show tns
```

The important separator here is the `&`, which indicates a second command within the same line.

Comment: It does not recognize show as a command because I am trying to execute show tns in the program that was just opened, not in cmd as well.

Comment: Oh I see. then you might need to create a batch file that runs both commands, the first from the command prompt, then the second from the started service

Comment: No way to do it in one line?

Comment: well if you create a batch file, then use the command prompt to run the file, that would be one line. Otherwise, there may be an option on the `start sql` command that would show the tns, but I have to look that up